# Pet weasel seems afraid of being on the ground

Tags: behavior, animal-handling, ferrets

I have a pet weasel. When she is up on my shoulders, she seem to be fine. She will be relaxed and calm. However, when I put her down on the ground, she seems to be very nervous, or afraid. She will run from people's feet, almost as if she is afraid of being stepped on. It's like she had a very traumatic experience in connection with a person's foot (stepped on, or something).

Can anyone give me some advice about how to help her overcome this problem?

Comment: @keshlam You got man...

Comment: @rahmandikahaekal I've attempted to re-word your question possibly more closely to your original. If you are OK with these edits, please approve them, if not, go ahead and reject them.

Comment: Is that fear, play, interest in things other than you...? Ferrets have two speeds, fast and sleeping. They aren't likely to stay next to you unless you are the most interesting thing happening or they are sleepy